# The Isin function within a loop doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a dataframe df like

```
 X      Y

110     0
110     0
110     1
111     1
111     0
112     1
113     1
114     0
```

When I filter the datsframe to make operation like len and sum everything works correctly, like here

```
new = df.x.isin([110,111])
df[new]
len(df[new].y) = 5
sum(df[new].y) = 2
```

However when I invoke the isin function inside a loop it doesn't work correctly.

I have second dataframe df0 like

```
col1 . col2

a     110,111
b     113
c     114,1114
d     267,118
e     956
```

and I want to iterate over df0 and do operation len and sum invoking group gr of element of df.x from df0.col2 like I do in this loop

```
for i in df0.index:
    gr = df0.get_value(i, 'col2')
    new = df.x.isin([gr])
    df_size = len(df[new].y)
    df_sum = sum(df[new].y)
```

the issue is that in the group gr=110,111 the element 111 is ignored

so the df_size = 3 and df_sum = 1 when instead they should be 5 and 2

Comment: what is the need of a for loop?

Comment: I have to iterate over each groups of the col2 in the dataframe df0

Comment: okay can you post the df0 in the same format as df, even better would be providing a dataframe constructor and expected output

Comment: what does mean the same format. They example of dataframe I am using already. My question is why the isin function doesn-t work in a loop

Comment: meaning , i am able to reproduce the first df using `pd.read_clipboard()` , but cant for the second one

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the second dataframe, I already have it. Use pd.DataFrame({'col1':...}, {col2:...}) dictionaries to reproduce the same that you see in the example

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make good, reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for help with making sample data that is easy to reproduce, to help us to help you more easily

Comment: I have encountered issues where `in` does not work because of float numbers errors. Is that the same issue here?

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks, I have just explained how to make the dataframe in a previous comment. You can do it yourself. The problem of the topic is another one.

Comment: @Guimoute there is any float number. It doesn't recognise the list of numbers like [110,111] but only single numbers or the first one in the list 110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the first line of your first code sample:

```
new = df.x.isin([110,111])
```

The argument of *isin* is a **list**.

Then look at `df.x.isin([gr])` in the second code sample and note that
if *gr* is e.g. `'111,112'` (a string) then `[gr]` contains
`['111,112']`, i.e. a list containing a **single** element.
The fact that you "enveloped" *gr* with square brackets does not split *gr*.

One of possible to cope with it solutions is to convert *col2*
the following way:

```
df0.col2 = df0.col2.str.split(',')
```

so that each element contains also a **list** (not a string).

Then change the second code sample to:

```
for _, row in df0.iterrows():
    new = df[df.x.isin(row.col2)]
    df_size = new.y.size
    df_sum = new.y.sum()
    print(row.col2, df_size, df_sum)
```

In the final version replace *print* with whatever you want to do with these
variables.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look. The only thing interrow is very slow, that't why I iterate with get_values and the gr variable. Do you think is is the same?

Comment: *iterrows* should work quicker than your loop over the index.
Note that in this case you perform an "individual search" for a row with the current index, what takes some time.
But when you use *iterrows*, you already have the current row retrieved (no need to search it again).